# Remove <a> within container

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="http://link.com">Link 1</a></li>
   <li class="remove-me"><a>Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://link.com">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I'd like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="http://link.com">Link 1</a></li>
   <li class="remove-me">Link 2</li>
   <li><a href="http://link.com">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I acheive this with jquery? I thought `$('.remove-me').removeAttr('a');` but that's not it?

Comment: `$('.remove-me a').remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Try [`$('.remove-me a').remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).</s>

**Edit:** I see that you want to preserve the contents of the `a` element(s).  In that case, using [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) should work:

```
$('.remove-me a').replaceWith( function() {
    return $(this).contents();
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

This will strip all HTML tags (including the `a`) from the `li`:

```
$('li.remove-me').text(function(i, text) { return text; });
```

If you just want to remove the `a` tags:

```
 $('li.remove-me a').replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.remove-me').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: That fails if there is more than one `.remove-me`. See my answer.

Comment: @Eric You are right, I added an `each`. Really liked your answer, very clean. You get +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

First thoughts, assuming you want to preserve the text inside the `li`:

```
$('li.remove-me').each(
    function(){
        $(this).text($(this).find('a').text()).find('a').remove();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UMeDQ/).

Or, alternatively:

```
var text = "";

$('li.remove-me').each(
    function(){
        text = $(this).text();
        $(this).empty().text(text);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UMeDQ/1/).

Answer (score 0):

This will strip only the `a` tag and preserve its contents:

```
$(".remove-me a").replaceWith(function(i, content) { return content; })
```

Comment: +1: I was surprised that it works, but it does!  But where the heck is that documented??

Comment: @Eric no, it will replace a with its content, preserving any tags inside such as img. See http://jsfiddle.net/fFLaq/

Comment: @Tetaxa: Nope, looks like intended behaviour. The second argument of the callback function is the content, not the same as `this`. Edit your answer, and I'll remove my all-too-hasty downvote.

Comment: Might be better to use `this.innerHTML` though, might be slightly faster.

Comment: @Tetaxa: Actually, I kind of doubt it -- straightforward DOM manipulation ought to be faster than serializing to HTML and back again.  Also, using `innerHTML` might lose things like attached event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:
`$('.remove-me a').replaceWith($('.remove-me a').text());`

Answer (score -1):

Try:
**1.**

```
var val= $('.remove-me').text();
$('.remove-me').empty().text(val);
```

or **2.**

```
var val= $('.remove-me').text();
$('.remove-me').html(val);
```

or **3.**

```
$('.remove-me').each(
    function(){
        $(this).html($("a", this).first().text());
});
```

[See the demo (contains all code)](http://jsfiddle.net/Javad_Amiry/tZCwH/)